# zoom google map to x linear miles in all directions using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I am trying to display map approx X linear miles on the horizontal and vertical  axis from center position. How can I display only 10 miles north,south,east,west from center point on google map ?

I am using below JavaScript to display map:

```
 function InitializeMap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 6,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: false
    };


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

}
```

[image: output map]

Answer (score 3):

You may use the geometry-library to calculate a LatLngBounds-instance for the desired area and use fitBounds to set the viewport of the map:

```js
function InitializeMap() {

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: false
    },


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions),
    bb = {
      n: 0,
      e: 90,
      s: 180,
      w: 270
    },
    miles = 10,
    r=miles*1609.34/2,
    b;

  for (var k in bb) {
    bb[k] = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latlng, r, bb[k]);
  }
  b = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(bb.s.lat(), bb.w.lng()),
    new google.maps.LatLng(bb.n.lat(), bb.e.lng())
  );
  map.fitBounds(b);
  new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });

  //the calculated area
  new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: b
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', InitializeMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks..  where can i set "x" miles  in your script

Comment: I've added a miles-variable to the script, set it to the desired value

Answer (score 1):

One option, use the `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset` method to compute a point 10 miles each direction from your "center point".

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function InitializeMap() {

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: false
  };


  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  var dist10mi = 10 * 1.60934 * 1000; // 10 miles * 1.60934 km/mi * 1000 m/km
  var north = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latlng, dist10mi, 0);
  var south = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latlng, dist10mi, 180);
  var east = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latlng, dist10mi, 90);
  var west = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latlng, dist10mi, 270);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  bounds.extend(north);
  bounds.extend(south);
  bounds.extend(east);
  bounds.extend(west);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: bounds
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", InitializeMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```